# org.grails.web.converters.exceptions.ConverterException: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException

Tags: java, exception

I an getting an exception like this

> org.grails.web.converters.exceptions.ConverterException:
>   java.util.ConcurrentModificationException

I am getting this exception from GCM Response, But  both are having a different behaviour but they are showing 2 exceptions seperated by a `":"` First time i saw thi exception.
Just want to know when 2 different types of exceptions are occuring seperated by a collon(:) .
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The exception is wrapped in another exception : http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-exception-handling/exception-wrapping.html